# Java Mergesort strings

Tags: java, string, sorting, mergesort

Im trying to make a method that will allow me to sort an array of Strings in Java using mergesort. I have looked at some code samples and made my own algorithm, but it doesnt seem to work and I am having some difficulty finding the issue. The code is as follows:

```
/*
 * Sorting methods, implemented using mergesort to sort the array of names
 * alphabetically
 */
public String[] sort(String[] array) {
    // check if the number of elements < 2
    if (array.length > 1) {

        // divide into two smaller arrays
        // determine length of two smaller arrays
        int arrLen1 = array.length;
        int arrLen2 = array.length - arrLen1;

        // populate smaller arrays with elements from initial array
        String[] array1 = new String[arrLen1];
        String[] array2 = new String[arrLen2];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrLen1; i++) {
            array[i] = array1[i];
        }

        for (int i = arrLen1; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = array2[i];
        }

        // now that we have the two halves, we can recursively call sort() on each to sort them
        array1 = sort(array1);
        array2 = sort(array2);

        // three counters are needed to keep track of where we are in the arrays, one for pos in final array, and one for each of the two halves
        // i => pos in main array
        // j => pos in array1
        // k => pos in array2
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (array1.length != j && array2.length != k) {
            if (array1[i].compareTo(array2[i]) < 0) {
                // copy current element of array1 to final array as it preceeds array2's current element
                array[i] = array1[j];

                // increment the final array so we dont overwrite the value we just inserted
                i++;
                // increment array1 which we took the element from so we dont compare it again
                j++;
            }
            // If the element in array2 preceeds the element in array1

            else {
                // copy current element of array1 to final array as it preceeds array1's current element
                array[i] = array2[j];
                // increment the final array so we dont overwrite the value we just inserted
                i++;
                // increment array2 which we took the element from so we dont compare it again
                k++;
            }
        }

        // at this point one of the sub arrays have been exhausted, and no more elements to compare
        while (array1.length != j) {
            array[i] = array1[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        while (array2.length != k) {
            array[i] = array2[k];
            i++;
            k++;

        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Try adding logging at each sort call and test with small arrays where you know how it should behave.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one you are trying to recursively sort before you actually do any comparing.

THe way your code is written, array1 is always equal to array, and then you call sort on array1 again, meaning you are just constantly going round the circle.